setting custom HTTP header based on HTTP error code (Apache 2.4)
I can't figure this out.
I'm trying to create an apache configuration applicable to all domains hosted on the same box so that if a request to any url returns an error-based code to the client (like 4xx or 5xx), a "connection: close" (keep-alive disabled) is also set in the HTTP headers for the client, whereas all the good requests will have keep-alive enabled.
I ask this because I think hackers are trying to tie up connections to my server by deliberately trying to access URLs that return errors (particularly the 404 not found error) and I want to make it so apache literally closes the connection on the errors.
And why the "connection: close" specifically? because cloudflare includes that header when it issues the 403 not authorized page when one accesses a homepage of a different site (because that site wants to perform human verification first).
Any way I can do this with just apache? or would I have to somehow write up an apache module (if its possible) to achieve this task?

From my understanding, you want to add a particular header depending on the request status of the client.
While you can't do that directly as an IF statement (per documentation), here's a workaround that accomplishes what you ask:
Header always set name-of-header  "header value" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == request-status"

Example, let's say you want to add a Connection:close header for 404 error codes:
Header always set Connection "close" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"

A few things to consider:

Using Connection and Keep-Alive headers is prohibited in HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. Plus the likelihood of slowing the attackers by using these headers is very low
Seems like you should try other techniques. If you say you are already using CloudFlare, try to identify patterns that you can block on the WAF level
You can also attempt to use the CloudFlare API and use their firewall to block the malicious users in real time (this requires programming knowledge)
You could try to enable Fail2Ban on your server to monitor and block the intrusions
Other things to consider are rate-limiting the connections, and/or enabling a load balancer

